# What is the mistake in my linked list code?

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

This is my code written in ANSI C.
I am constantly getting run-time error: Segmentation Fault (SIGSEGV).
Please help me out.
I am new to data structures and C.
I am unable to detect the problem.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *nxt;
}node;

node * create(int n);
void display(node *head);

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    node *head = NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes\n");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    head = create(n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}

node * create(int n)
{
    int i;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        printf("\nEnter the value of %d node", i + 1);
        scanf("%d", &temp->data);
        temp->nxt = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            p = head;
            while (p->nxt != NULL)
            {
                p = p->nxt;
                p->nxt = temp;
            }

        }

    }
    return head;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    node *p = NULL;
    if (head = NULL)
    {
        printf("\nEmpty List");
    }
    else
    {
        p = head;
        while (p != NULL);
        {
            printf("%d->", p->data);
            p = p->nxt;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your code is hard to read. Please edit your question to apply proper indentation. Apart from that this is the time when you should start thinking about using a debugger like GDB. It should show you, where your SIGSEGV happens which is a good starting point to search for the bug.

Comment: Your error is in the loop `while(p->nxt!=NULL)` where you repeatedly assign `temp`. Take a debugger and step through the code.

Comment: In the display code, you have an unwanted semicolon after the while loop: `while (p != NULL);` — that pretty much guarantees a crash in the `printf()` call after it if `p` is null, or an infinite loop if it is not null.  Neither is desirable.  Also, before that, you zap your `head` pointer with the assignment in `if (head = NULL)`.  Most modern compilers will warn about that.  If yours didn't, find the options to make it do so, or get a better, more modern compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Thomas Jager](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5567382/thomas-jager) gives you an important fix in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50585487/15168).  I gave you two important fixes in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585396/what-is-the-mistake-in-my-linked-list-code?noredirect=1#comment88180448_50585396).  When those are combined, the code works for me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *nxt;
} node;

node *create(int n);
void display(node *head);

static void error(const char *msg)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", msg);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int main(void)
{
    int n = 0;
    node *head = NULL;
    printf("Enter the number of nodes: ");
    if (scanf("%d", &n) != 1)
        error("failed to read an integer");
    head = create(n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}

node *create(int n)
{
    int i;
    node *head = NULL;
    node *temp = NULL;
    node *p = NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        if (temp == NULL)
            error("failed to allocate memory");
        printf("\nEnter the value of %d node: ", i + 1);
        if (scanf("%d", &temp->data) != 1)
            error("failed to read an integer");
        temp->nxt = NULL;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            p = head;
            while (p->nxt != NULL)
            {
                p = p->nxt;
            }
            p->nxt = temp;
        }
        display(head);   // Debugging - check the list as it is built
    }
    return head;
}

void display(node *head)
{
    node *p = NULL;
    if (head == NULL)
    {
        printf("Empty List\n");
    }
    else
    {
        p = head;
        while (p != NULL)
        {
            printf("%d->", p->data);
            p = p->nxt;
            fflush(stdout);     // Band-aid - remove ASAP
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    fflush(stdout);     // Band-aid - remove ASAP
}
```

I used the `display` function inside the input code to make sure the list is working cleanly at all times.  It accounts for the extra copies of the list shown below.  The code also terminates lines of output with a newline, which helps ensure it appears.  There are two documented "remove me" calls to `fflush(stdout)` that aren't needed, but are helpful while debugging if your code crashes.  There's a partial argument that the prompting `printf()` calls should be followed by a `fflush(stdout)` to ensure that the prompt appears.  It isn't usually necessary for interactive output.

Note that I added an error-reporting function to make it easy to report errors, and therefore provide encouragement to detect possible errors.  You can see my preferred error handling code in my [SOQ](https://github.com/jleffler/soq) (Stack Overflow Questions) repository on GitHub as files `stderr.c` and `stderr.h` in the [src/libsoq](https://github.com/jleffler/soq/tree/master/src/libsoq) sub-directory.

When I'm working with a data structure (e.g. a list), I usually create myself a `dump_list()` function.  There are normally 2 or 3 arguments:

```
void dump_list(const char *tag, const node *list);
void dump_list(FILE *fp, const char *tag, const node *list);
```

The 'tag' argument is used to annotate the output:

```
dump_list(__func__, head);  // In create()

dump_list("result", head);  // In main()
```

The tag is important; it allows you to create a distinct marker for each place where you use the function (I've used `dump_list("point 1", …)`, `dump_list("point 2", …)`, … inside a single function on many an occasion).
If I think I might need it to go to other than standard output (standard error, for example, or to a log file), I provide myself with the version with the `FILE *` argument.  Using this allows you to check your data structure.  Note that the function isn't allowed to modify the data structure.  You could have a different format for the `display()` function from the `dump_list()` function — in which case you'd not call `dump_list()` in the `main()` function.  But having such a function available to validate your data structure can help enormously.

With the code shown, I can run the program (`ll53` created from `ll53.c`, compiled cleanly with GCC 8.1 set fussy), like this:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes \
>     -Wstrict-prototypes ll53.c -o ll53 
$ ./ll53
Enter the number of nodes: 1

Enter the value of 1 node: 234
234->
234->
$ ./ll53
Enter the number of nodes: 2 

Enter the value of 1 node: 234
234->

Enter the value of 2 node: 123
234->123->
234->123->
$ ./ll53
Enter the number of nodes: 7

Enter the value of 1 node: 987
987->

Enter the value of 2 node: 888
987->888->

Enter the value of 3 node: 789
987->888->789->

Enter the value of 4 node: 345
987->888->789->345->

Enter the value of 5 node: 444
987->888->789->345->444->

Enter the value of 6 node: 543
987->888->789->345->444->543->

Enter the value of 7 node: 0
987->888->789->345->444->543->0->
987->888->789->345->444->543->0->
$ ./ll53
Enter the number of nodes: 0
Empty List
$
```

Answer (score 2):

At this part:

```
    while(p->nxt!=NULL)
    {
        p=p->nxt;
        p->nxt=temp;
    }
```

I think the `p->nxt=temp;` should be outside the loop, like this:

```
    while(p->nxt!=NULL)
    {
        p=p->nxt;
    }
    p->nxt=temp;
```

Comment: Good answer Thomas, however the while loop wont work due to the ';' at the end of while in the original example.